# How to solve a decomposition model in pyomo?

Tags: optimization, iteration, hierarchy, pyomo, decomposition

I am trying to solve a model in pyomo(using cplex solver) which consists of a master-problem and a subproblem. The variable of the master problem is the parameter for the subproblem and vice versa. these two problems(master and subproblem) solve sequentially and repeatedly until the termination condition holds. Can any one assist me how can solve this problem in pyomo?
I have tried this:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverStatus, TerminationCondition
###############MasterProblem#########################################
objective_value=[]
sigma=2
model1= AbstractModel()
model1.z1=Param(model1.i,initialize=0,mutable=True) 
model1.z2=Param(model1.i,initialize=39,mutable=True)
model1.x=Var(model1.t, within=Reals)
model1.X=Var(model1.t, within=Reals)
opt=SolverFactory('cplex')
instance1=model1.create_instance()
results1=opt.solve(instance1)
objective_value.append(value(instance1.of))
########subproblem#####################
model= AbstractModel()
model.x=Param(model.t,initialize=instance1.x, mutable=True)
model.X=Param(model.t,initialize=instance1.X, mutable=True)
model.z1=Var(model.i,within=Reals)
model.z2=Var(model.i,within=Reals)
instance=model.create_instance()
results=opt.solve(instance)
while len(objective_value)<2 or (objective_value[-2]-objective_value[-1])>sigma:
 instance1.z1=instance.z1
instance1.z2=instance.z2
results1=opt.solve(instance1)
objective_value.append(value(instance1.of)) 
instance.x=instance1.x
instance.X=instance1.X
results=opt.solve(instance)
```

Comment: I get this error:                                                                                                      
RuntimeError: Re-assigning the component 'z1' from block 'unknown' to
block 'unknown' as 'z1'.

This behavior is not supported by Pyomo; components must have a
single owning block (or model), and a component may not appear
multiple times in a block.  If you want to re-name or move this
component, use the block del_component() and add_component() methods.

Comment: should I use a block structure for this problem?